# Facebook application authorize callback URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook application which can be added to a facebook fan page as custom tab. In the application setting I can see "Deauthorize Callback" which sends a signed request with page details when a user removes application from a page to the specified URL. Is there an option to specify an authorize callback URL which receives a request with page details when user first installs the application to the page.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, there was an authorize callback.  So, your question is perfectly reasonable.

Facebook has removed it from the app settings form.  So probably it is gone for good, but I have not seen any "official" word on the matter.  (i.e. zero heads up that the feature is going away.)

You'll still find the property, authorize_url, on the [wildly out-of-date application properties page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/).  But its anybody's guess whether they will continue to call that callback, if you happened to set it before it was removed from the form.

Answer (score 5):

Once the user authorizes/or does not authorize your app, he is redirected to the "redirect_uri" that you specified in authentication url.

If the user presses Don't Allow, your app is not authorized. The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the redirect_uri parameter with the following error information:

`http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&
     error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.`

If the user presses Allow, your app is authorized. The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the redirect_uri parameter with an authorization code:

`http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER`

you could always check for error_reason and error parameters in the callback action to establish that the user did not authorize the app.

Complete documentation here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to add application to facebook fan page using http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=<api_key>&pages=1&page=<page_id>. The user selects the application and facebook fan page from my site. Using this URL the user is led to facebook site where he has to publish application to page. But the user can choose not to. Couldn't find any callback which can be used to identify that the user has not published the application to facebook.

Comment: The link takes me to my home page. As I have already told you that the callback is called in both the cases, whether the user authorizes the app or not. You need to put in the right code to check for the error condition in your callback function i.e. check for the error parameter in the url. Look at the url format above and spend some time reading the documentation. I hope "publish application to page" means authorize the facebook app to publish.

Answer (score 2):

No, Facebook does not offer an post-authorization equivalent of the deauthorize callback.

You don't need that, though: Once a user has authorized your application, you'll find the user's credentials and access token in the [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to allow users to add an tab from my site. The user is authorized using facebook connect api. The list of user's fan  page is displayed in my site. The user can select one page and publish to facebook. I store the page details at that point but the user may choose not to install after going to facebook.com. Wanted to track such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this in the setting of your app in Facebook.

Go to setting menu, then advanced tab, then find "OAuth setting". You will have an input called "Valid OAuth redirect URIs", you can enter several URL here.

I used it for Cordova Facebook auth, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is now located in the Facebook developer tools under "Products > Facebook Login > Settings". You'll see a section for "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"... hope that helps somebody.